# Alias column not mapping to property on entity when using SqlQuery in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am using a raw SQL statement that I have an aliased column called "Distance" which I would like to store the value into a new property on my entity's partial class.  However, when I execute the query, entity framework maps everything except this aliased column.  What should I be doing to map the aliased column Distance to the property Distance on my class?

**Partial Class**

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(ParishMD))]
    public partial class Parish
    {

        public List<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
        public double Distance { get; set; }

        .........
    }
```

**Controller Class Method**

```
string SQL = "select * from (select *, Distance = ((ACOS(SIN({0} * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS({0} * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(({1} - Long) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) from dbo.Parish) t where Distance < 10 order by Distance asc";

 SqlParameter latParam = new SqlParameter("latitude", latitude);
 SqlParameter lngParam = new SqlParameter("longitude", longitude);
 object[] parameters = new object[] { latitude, longitude };


 var parishes = db.Parish.SqlQuery(SQL, parameters);
```

I have around 12 properties on this class that I mapped in the EDMX file that maps to the database table and those properties are mapped correctly.  The *Distance* property is not a column on my table so its not in the EDMX. Not sure if this is why I am not mapping.

Thanks for any help!

Flea

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Arg0n  Don't remember. I solved it, but not sure how any more.